# Organizing tags with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, rubymotion

I'm fairly new to Interface Builder (I'm using RubyMotion, btw), and would like to see how others organize their view tags. I have a lot of view components that really should be grouped together, like a UILabel on top of a UIView.

My initial thoughts are to have a single function that takes care of all the mapping of view tags to view objects. Something like this:

```
def mapTags
  @awesomeButton = AwesomeButton.new(
    :view => view.viewWithTag 1,
    :label => view.viewWithTag 2
  )
end

def viewDidLoad
  self.mapTags
end
```

This still isn't very satisfactory, which is why I'm hoping someone much more experienced/clever can offer a superior solution.

Answer (score 2):

well if you need to tag all your views and you have alot of em, i suggest you do it whenever you initialize a view instead of separating it in a function,  that is the safest way. In objective-c, i usually create specific macro's for each tag and then whenever i initialize the view, i assign the macro for that tag, ex:

```
#define kMyFirstViewTag 2
#define kMyLabelTag     3

...

[myFirstView setTag:kMyFirstViewTag];
```

This way you can group certain views by name (`kMyGroup1LabelTag`) and you can access them easily by tag name.

I dont know much about ruby, but im pretty sure there should be a way to achieve the same result.

Hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. That's essentially what I'm doing with Ruby. I guess I wish Interface Builder didn't constrain tag names to just integers--then I could name my elements in IB. So for grouping, there is no way to express in IB that two elements belong together? That part must be entirely done in code?

Comment: well theres no such thing as 'grouping' in IB. I dont know exactly what you are trying to do but if you have `UIView`s embedded as `subviews` in a parent `UIView`, they are in a way grouped. Of course i wouldnt do that just for the sake of 'grouping' them. If it is just for referral and organizing things, then id say you only have name tagging.